# Checking type of an enum

Tags: typescript

Given

```
enum myEnum {
    a,b,c
}

var myEnum1: myEnum = myEnum.a;
```

How should I check `myEnum1` is of type `myEnum`?

If I use

```
typeof myEnum1
```

it will simply say that it is a `number` rather than `myEnum`

Comment: What is the motivation behind your question? I mean why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

> it will simply say that it is a number rather than myEnum

At runtime it will be *number* (baring something hacky where you loose the compile time safety).

However look at the code gen for Enum :

```
enum MyEnum {
    A
}
```

You get :

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["A"] = 0] = "A";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

so given `MyEnum[num]` is truthy its safe to assume that its a valid member.

More : Such conversions are discussed [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html)